# Is it possible to set DNS for mobile network

Tags: cyanogenmod, networking, 4.4-kitkat, mobile-network, dns

I live in Canada and use an unblocking service to access US Netflix content, Pandora and Hulu. I would like to be able to use this service while not on my WiFi is there a way to set the DNS server to the ones i need for my unblocker to work for the mobile network

Comment: I personally use Eddy Pey's DNS Changer app, though reviews on it say it doesn't work with kitkat.

Comment: boo guess ill have to wait for an update theres a few i saw through google but none are working on kit kat yet and a lot of them only change your wifi dns,  no way to do this through a hidden setting or build prop eh?  hacked carrier bundle maybe?

Comment: [How to configure DNS properly?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the `cyanogenmod` an `KitKat` tags on the question, so I suppose you own a rooted device with Android 4.4.

In general there is a good number of apps on the Play Store which are able to change the DNS for mobile connections of pre Android 4.4 devices and [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mx17.overridedns) (which I wrote and sell) which changes the DNS on Android 4.4 devices.

If you need the raw commands, here they are (need root):

```
# ndc resolver flushif <iface>
# ndc resolver flushdefaultif
# ndc resolver setifdns <iface> <dns1> <dns2>
# ndc resolver setdefaultif <iface>
```

My answer to a similar question is [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62081/how-to-change-mobile-connectionss-dns-on-android-kitkat/71615#71615) and contains references to my app.

Comment: i was using cyanogen at the time i bricked the device a while ago but i have left the question open for others who may need the info looks like a viable solution i will check them out

Answer (score 2):

When I needed to change my DNS the solution was always [SETDNS](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.mytechie.setDNS). It's light, fast and user-friendly.

Be aware that if your phone isn't rooted SetDNS will only modify WiFi' DNS settings...

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an up-to-date answer, I wrote an App which changes the DNS of both Wifi and mobile connections also without root. Have a look at [PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aykutcevik.dnschanger&utm_source=global_co&utm_medium=prtnr&utm_content=Mar2515&utm_campaign=PartBadge&pcampaignid=MKT-AC-global-none-all-co-pr-py-PartBadges-Oct1515-1) or [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01862KUFI).