# USB thethering netdns set

Tags: usb-tethering, dns

Im Trying to create network emulation using USB tethering on KK.

The problem is that I cant set net.dns to my host ip, and therefore any dns resolution is answered with *Unknown Host*.

I read that

> $ setprop net.dns1 *ip-address*

Does not work in KK. So is there a way to work around that and set the netdns to be the ip-address of my usb network interface?

Thanks

Comment: You could see if [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/71624/61821) applies to your case.